# How to fetch tabular data from the web to an Android app using Java

Tags: java, android, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch **Report coronavirus cases** table data from https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ to my Android app using Java.

[image: Report coronavirus cases]

So I have an object called country and instance of the object are countryName, TotalCase, Total death, etc. and then I will store the object in an arrayList.

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SammaryHandler extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            Document document= Jsoup.connect("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/").userAgent("mozilla/17.0").get();
//            Elements temp= document.select("table table-bordered table-hover main_table_countries dataTable no-footer");

            Elements temp= document.select("table.dataTable");//?????????????????

            int size= temp.size();
            for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
                String data= temp.select("table.dataTable").eq(i).attr("");//?????????????
                System.out.println(data);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

So how can I read all of the data from the table and save load in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah just as an information for you from their website - it is not permitted to use their data without buying a license.

But answering your question. I see mainly that you haven't applied proper CSSQuery. 
Try this code:

```
      //connect to the website
final String url =
                "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";
//surround by try catch
        try {
            final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    //create a list of what you need from the table. we will read data by each column
            List<String> countrieNames = null;
//loop by elements in the table
        for (Element row : document.select("table#main_table_countries_today tr")) {
//filter as there are empty rows or others to be filtered
                        if (row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text().equals("") || row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text().equals("Total:")) {
                              continue;
                            }
//save informations you need to the created list
                            countrieNames = document.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").eachText();

        }
//print out results
for (int i = 0; i < countrieNames.size(); i=i+2) {
                    System.out.println(countrieNames.get(i));
                }
} catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```